# framework7 rtl prev/next button in photo-browser

Tags: html, right-to-left, html-framework-7, swiper.js

I have a problem with "photo-browser-prev,photo-browser-next" button
It does not work properly

Сheck this
[image]

Its 2 of 3 but prev button is disable and when i use this style it work

```
.photo-browser-swiper-container {
      direction: ltr;
}
```

but swiper direction is wrong.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SOF! Please take a time to visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it more understandable!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, and I fix it by this:

```
var yourPhotoObj = app.photoBrowser.create({......});

    /* Fixing F7 Bug in PhotoBroswer Prev Link Image */
    $$(document).on('click', '.photo-browser-prev', function(e){
        fixingF7PrevButtonIssueInRtl(true);
    });

    $$(document).on('click', '.photo-browser-next', function(e){
        fixingF7PrevButtonIssueInRtl();
    });

    function fixingF7PrevButtonIssueInRtl(removeOne = false)
    {
        if(langVarialbeDirection == 'rtl'){// Change langVarialbeDirection to your direction
            if(!yourPhotoObj || !yourPhotoObj.opened){// exit if photoBroswer object not declared
                return;
            }

            if(removeOne){
                yourPhotoObj.open(yourPhotoObj.activeIndex - 1);
            }

            if(yourPhotoObj.activeIndex != 0){
                $('.photo-browser-prev').removeClass('swiper-button-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', false);
            }else{
                $('.photo-browser-prev').addClass('swiper-button-disabled').attr('aria-disabled', true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Explain code:
This code will get event from photoBroweser, and then call our custom function, this function will remove disabled from prev button if number of image is more than 0, also you need to pass true if like to enable view prev image when click on button above code...I wish its fix your issue.

Note: You can use custom event in photobroser like this too If you have a special cases in your photoBroser:

```
on: {
                    opened: function(){
                        fixingF7PrevButtonIssueInRtl();
                    },
                    lazyImageLoad: function(){
                        fixingF7PrevButtonIssueInRtl();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: hi. thanks for reply. your code is find and work good. but there is 2 problem. when you swipe on last pic, next button didn't disable. and when you click on next again then click back it swipe to first pic. i just fix first one . but the second one didn't work. try to prevent click but also don't work. forget to say i use Framework7 3.5.2.

Comment: For swipe, you need to define event listener like next & prev..I think that